# Data access in activity from service running in separate process causing

Tags: android

My location service is running in separate process and sending location objects stored in an arraylist every 2mins through broadcast receiver to maps activity, which draws path of movement. But there is delay in data access when maps acitivity comes back to foreground. How can I get location data instantly from location service stored in arraylist object when activity comes to foreground.

I have made location service in separate process so as to gain wakelock when phone dozes. How can I get location data on demand from service to activity in onResume method.

I understand I can use bound service to implement that but I fear breaking wakelock in some devices.

Right now, I am directly accessing static location arraylist object from service to activity but I don't feel this is right approach.

Comment: you dont need your service to be hosted by a separate process - it only makes your data transfer more complex

Comment: I understand that but my application runs in background to track user location every 2mins. So if I don't keep my service in foreground and in a separate process it gets killed by doze. So i am helpless to run it in separate process.